# Make Web Activity work with response that's not a proper Json

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Web Activity to make a POST request to a slack webhook.
The problem is that the slack webhook responds with a 200 and an "ok" string as the body of the response and the web activity doesn't seems to like that because I'm getting the error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "Response Content is not a valid JObject",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "activityName"
}
```

So my question is if there is a workaround for this or is there is an alternative to use web activity. For the time being I know I can use a custom activity and even I'm thinking of setting up an azure function that acts as a proxy and thus returns a proper Json.

Note: I'm using this slack integration to alert when something goes wrong. Of course I'm also open to suggestions on how to alert my team when something is not working in ADF (sending an email wouldn't work because our inboxes are completely cluttered, so slack seemed like a good alternative for a change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookup activity with an HTTP dataset. You can define the dataset to be a REST call, and I don't think the lookup activity is picky about the response format.

Another option might be to use an Azure Logic App to update Slack. You can either use it as a 'proxy' to be called by ADF, or see if it can be set up to perform the monitoring you want as well.

Comment: Yeah, lookup activity isn't picky about the response format.

I ended up going the Lookup+Azure Function way but Logic App would have been practically the same :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#type-properties), REST endpoints that the web activity invokes **must return a response of type JSON**. The activity will timeout at 1 minute with an error if it does not receive a response from the endpoint.

So currently I think your workaround should be the right way.

And besides of email, I think ADF also provides other approaches to monitor your data factory. Please find [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor) for more details.